# Django ModelForm - form display values

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a model:

```
class SchedulerProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.user)
```

I also have a model that has a M2M relationship with the Scheduler:

```
class OfficialProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    schedulers = models.ManyToManyField(SchedulerProfile, verbose_name="Your schedulers", related_name="off_schedulers")
```

When I create a ModelForm from the OfficialProfile, the form renders the contents of the scheduler multiselect as the username.  I'd like to get it to display `user.first_name user.last_name` in the field instead of the user.  I know I can change the unicode return value to accomplish this, but I'd rather not do that for reasons.  In the `__init__` of the ModelForm, you should be able to do something like:

```
self.fields['schedulers'].queryset = SchedulerProfile.objects.values('user__first_name', 'user__last_name')
```

But that doesn't produce the desired results.  This seems like a really basic question, but searching for the answer hasn't revealed much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclass [`ModelMultipleChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) and override `label_from_instance`.

```
from django.forms import ModelMultipleChoiceField

class SchedulerProfileChoiceField(ModelMultipleChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return "%s %s" % (obj.first_name, obj.last_name)
```

Then use your multiple choice field in the model form.

```
class OfficialProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    schedulers = SchedulerProfileChoiceField(queryset=SchedulerProfile.objects.all())
```