# How to display a field from a modelchoice

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, modelchoicefield

I have a class in my forms and a object called tiposervico (ForeignKey). See bellow.
In my template, after select a tiposervico I would like to display 'descricao' field on my screen. How can i do that?

```
class servicoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    tiposervico = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=tiposervico.objects.all(), required=True)
```

tiposervico -> id, descricao

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: I think you might be looking for `label_from_instance`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30464819/django-modelform-form-display-values/30465065#30465065).

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `label_from_instance` of the `field` inside the `get_form()` method in CBV and get access to the field with `lambda`

```
def get_form(self, form_class=None):
    form = super(ModelView, self).get_form()
    form.fields['field_name'].label_from_instance = lamda x : x.model_field_name_to_display
    return form
```

For FBV, you can do so after initializing your form;

```
form = FormName()
form.fields['field_name'].label_from_instance = lamda x : x.model_field_name_to_display
```